# Unable to pass POST parameter to Django view

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views, http-post

I've created a Django view and an accompanying url. I'm trying to get this view to accept a POST parameter, but this thing isn't working. It's part of a custom app I'm setting up to send push notifications to mobile devices.

My views.py is:

```
class DeviceCreateView(FormView):
    model = DeviceObj
    form_class = DeviceForm
    template_name = "deviceobj_form.html"
    def form_valid(self, form): 
        if self.request.method == 'POST':
            reg_id = self.request.POST.get("registration_id")
            DeviceObj.objects.create(registration_id=reg_id)
```

My urls.py is:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^$', home, name='home'),
    url(r'^registration_id/$', DeviceCreateView.as_view(), name='registration_id'),
    url(r'^success/$', success, name='success'), 
]
```

And my template is:

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'registration_id' %}">
{% csrf_token %}
<input type="hidden" name="registration_id" value="{{ registration_id }}">
</form>
```

I'm using the [POSTER](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/poster/) add-on on Mozilla to try sending a POST parameter to the arrangement above. I POST to http://www.fakeurl.com/registration_id, set parameter name to "registration_id" and then give it an example value (e.g. "testing123"). In response, I get a 200 status, with the following dump:

```
<form method="POST" action="/registration_id/">
<input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='PAPSwkpe1rU9c9ln4Jz0i6QKeyT57Cdf' />
<input type="hidden" name="registration_id" value="">
</form>
```

If I do the same via manual entry (i.e. remove type="hidden" from the input tag), it works perfectly. But with using POSTER, I can't seem to get a 201 (Created) response (i.e. nothing shows up in my database). This thing has been bothering me for days now!

Comment: there is problem with your form_valid function, you are redirecting to a template without any context variables.

Comment: Fair enough, I'll fix that. But that's not fatal right? My view should nevertheless be accepting the POST parameter, no?

Comment: Django doesn't produce 201s from a form post unless you've specifically written some code to make it do so. The post you've shown here should result in a 503 error because you're missing the csrf token. Are you sure you're posting to the correct URL - eg do you need a trailing slash?

Comment: I'll check. Thanks for heading out here btw!

Comment: Got it. CSRF token and trailing slash were the culprit. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unclear what you're trying to do with this hidden field, but you should be loading fields via the "form" variable in your template.

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'registration_id' %}">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form }}
</form>
```

If you need a field to be hidden, try adding this to your form (I'm assuming you're using a ModelForm, you didn't specify):

```
class DeviceForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = DeviceObj
        fields = ['registration_id']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(DeviceForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['registration_id'].widget = forms.HiddenInput()
```

**UPDATE**

As noted in the comments below, the problem was that the post made via the Mozilla POSTER add-on was missing a csrf_token. Adding it in allowed the post to go through.

Comment: Hmm, you're suggesting {{ form.as_p }} and using HiddenInput() in my view as a solution to the problem I have with accepting the POST parameter?

Comment: Not in your view, the hidden input goes in the DeviceForm which is then passed to the template. Then in your form_valid() method you can access the posted values directly: `device_obj = form.save()`

Comment: Sadly, the suggestion didn't work... Can you point me to a simple step-by-step guide of how to get a Django server to accept a POST parameter from a client? I'm trying to register devices' registration_ids to set up Google Cloud Messaging push notifications. If I can make a simple example run, I take care of the rest of the problem.

Comment: Django servers accept POST parameters from clients all the time, that's what's supposed to happen by default--your browser is a client which in theory shouldn't be treated any differently from the Mozilla plugin you're using. What happens if you set the form field to visible, load the DeviceCreateView URL with a browser and post from there? Try printing out the POST from this situation, and the POST from the plugin, and compare.

Comment: Also, I amended my answer to include the form with {{ form }}, rather than use as_table or as_p. This will print any errors associated with the form when FormView receives an invalid form and reloads the template.

Comment: so to post from a browser under my scheme, a url such as this should do the trick right: http://127.0.0.1:8000/registration_id/?registration_id=123456

Comment: nope, that is an HTTP GET. if all is configured properly, you can go to the URL 127.0.0.1:800/registration_id and you'll se a form with the fields from your DeviceForm. you can then populate the fields, click submit (which reminds me.. your form should have a submit button included after {{ form }}), and this will generate the POST.

Comment: Doing it manually like that's actually been working for me since day 1. I'm trying to now use browser plugins (e.g. HttpRequester for Mozilla) to achieve the same affect. THAT is what doesn't work for me. The plugin is unable to successfully deliver its payload, making me believe my form isn't primed to take a POST parameter.

Comment: Can you add the line: `if self.request.method == 'POST':
            print self.request.POST` and compare the output of manual vs HttpRequester?

Comment: Actually I debugged the issue yesterday. For the most part, I had skipped the CSRF token value when POSTing from HttpRequester. That, and the feedback you gave me above helped me solve the issue! Thanks a bunch for keying in. If you can edit your answer to include CSRF addition, I'll mark it as the correct one and close this question :-)

Comment: Glad to hear you resolved it. I've updated my answer, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Two concerns

1. `form_valid()` is called when valid form data has been POSTed, so you don't need to check for GET/POST, you can check the example in django doc - 
   https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormView
2. `redirect()` accepts a model/view-name/url, not just a template name
   https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/http/shortcuts/

Comment: Fair enough, I've noted that and will make the changes. But neither (1) nor (2) are fatal right? This thing should still be working (and it does when I do it manually via a text field).